# Pattern to exclude specific channels from global wire-tap

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a global wire-tap that I use for audit purposes. Since the wire-tap doesn't get a clone of the message from the channel, I extract certain attributes from the message and forward it another (asynchronous) channel where it gets persisted. So in a sense, the wire-tap has it's own sub-flow. I realize that the wire-tap doesn't tap itself but I would like it to not tap any channels that are part of the persistence sub-flow either.

I realize that wire-tap has a pattern but it doesn't seem to accept a regular expression to exclude channels that should not be globally tapped. What is the format for providing an exclusion pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `@GlobalChannelInterceptor` JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * An array of simple patterns against which channel names will be matched. Default is "*"
 * (all channels). See {@link org.springframework.util.PatternMatchUtils#simpleMatch(String, String)}.
 * @return The pattern.
 */
String[] patterns() default "*";
```

So, according to the `PatternMatchUtils.simpleMatch` we can:

```
* Match a String against the given pattern, supporting the following simple
* pattern styles: "xxx*", "*xxx", "*xxx*" and "xxx*yyy" matches (with an
* arbitrary number of pattern parts), as well as direct equality.
```

As you see we can't *negate* the pattern.

From other side I think we can overcome the limitation. As you see the `WireTap` implements `VetoCapableInterceptor` with simple logic like:

```
public boolean shouldIntercept(String beanName, ChannelInterceptorAware channel) {
    return !this.channel.equals(channel);
}
```

So, you can extend this `WireTap` class and add more logic to the overrode method. After that you should register it in the XML config as a `<bean>` for the `<int:channel-interceptor>`.

Comment: @GaryRussell Is there a way for me to leverage the parsing logic for wire-tap when I extend the class to be able to pass the message channel?

Comment: M-m-m. Sorry, re-phrase, please. I didn't get it. If you'd like to pass the wire-tap channel, than that might not have sense and the more: you end up with the `StackOverflowError` sending message from the wire-tap to the wire-tapped channel.

Comment: I understand. My question is that when I extend the WireTap class, say with my own class, GlobalWireTap, how do I pass the output channel to it in my configuration xml? For example, when we directly use wire-tap, we are able to pass an output channel to it which becomes the secondary target. How do I achieve the same for my GlobalWireTap class

Comment: Well, looks like I don't understand you because you use some other terminology... Let me guess. "pass the output channel" means - "inject the wire-tap channel". Not sure what is "secondary target", but any component can be configured in the XML using regular `<bean>` definition.

Comment: Due to the length limitation on a comment, I'll post a response to the question with my experience in going about implementation. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Using Artem's suggestion, I was able to solve this problem but I had a couple of hiccups along the way so I'll just leave a shell of my implementation here in case some one else has the same issue:

The first thing I did was implement a class that extends the WireTap class. The class looks like so -

```
package org.mycompany.interceptors;

import org.springframework.integration.channel.ChannelInterceptorAware;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap;
import org.springframework.integration.support.context.NamedComponent;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;

public class GlobalWireTap extends WireTap {

    public GlobalWireTap(MessageChannel channel) {
        super(channel);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldIntercept(String beanName, ChannelInterceptorAware interceptChannel) {
        NamedComponent incomingChannel = (NamedComponent) interceptChannel;
        String channelName = incomingChannel.getComponentName();
        /* logic to determine if this channel should be intercepted */
        if (channelName.startsWith("DNT")) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

As you can see the incoming parameter is of type ChannelInterceptorAware. However, the ChannelInterceptorAware doesn't tell me much about the Channel so I cast it to a NamedComponent (which every type of Channel implements) and inspect the id of the channel to decide if I want to intercept this channel. Please note that in the WireTap class the channel attribute is private so you can't do something like - this.channel in your sub-class.

The corresponding configuration looks something like this:

```
<int:channel-interceptor pattern="*" ref="globalWireTap"></int:channel-interceptor>

<bean id="globalWireTap"
    class="org.mycompany.interceptors.GlobalWireTap">
    <constructor-arg ref="nullChannel" />
</bean>
```

For now I am redirecting all the messages to nullChannel but you can forward it to any channel.